# Send message continuously

Tags: android, client-server

I am developing an application in which client sends messages to server and server receives messages. But in my application when I am sending message, it is received by server only once. If I have to send message again to server I have to Force close the application and then again send message. Means in continuous manner I have to send data to server. Below is my code. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView serverMessage;
Thread m_objThreadClient;
Socket clientSocket;
private boolean connected = false;

EditText et;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        serverMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }



  public void Start(View view)
{
     // m_objThreadClient.start();
    m_objThreadClient=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
           {

              try
               {

                 clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.0.103",2000);
                 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                 oos.writeObject(et.getText().toString());
                 Message serverMessage= Message.obtain();
                 ObjectInputStream ois =new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                 String strMessage = (String)ois.readObject();
                 serverMessage.obj=strMessage;
                 mHandler.sendMessage(serverMessage);

                 oos.close();
                 ois.close();

              }

              catch(Exception e)
                     {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }


          }
            });

    m_objThreadClient.start();
    //m_objThreadClient.resume();

}
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        messageDisplay(msg.obj.toString());
    }
};
public void messageDisplay(String servermessage)
{
    serverMessage.setText(""+servermessage);
    m_objThreadClient.start();
}

}
```

Comment: share your stack trace (error log from logcat)

Answer (score 0):

Socket can be binded when you call start function again.
Validate this case.

```
 if(clientSocket != null && clientSocket.isConnected)clientSocket.close();
  clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.0.103",2000);
```

Comment: @Yahor10..Thank you.Your code is working.But where should I put this code.It is not giving any output. I am just getting message Open and Close from server.But no Output.

Comment: Put it before clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.0.103",2000);

Answer (score 0):

First make the `clientSocket` object local.

Then for solving the looping problem try this:

Call the function `starteMessageThreadRunner`, it will start the thread which will send the message to the server and as soon as the runnable will finish sending the data, it will again call the handler which in turn will call the thread again.

```
    /**
         * start the thread and handler which will send the message
         */
        public void starteMessageThreadRunner() {

            Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, "");
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }

        /**
         * handler for calling the thread.
         */
        Handler handler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // do something with the response received (if you want to)
                 serverMessage.setText(msg.obj.toString());
                //this line will call runnable again and will send the message to the server.
                handler.post(runnable);

            };
        };


        /**
         * A runnable object for calling the handler.
         */
        private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // send the message to the server.

try
               {

                 Socket clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.0.103",2000);
                 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                 oos.writeObject(et.getText().toString());
                 Message serverMessage= Message.obtain();
                 ObjectInputStream ois =new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());


                 String strMessage = (String)ois.readObject();
Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, strMessage );

                 oos.close();
                 ois.close();
handler.sendMessage(message);
              }

              catch(Exception e)
                     {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }



            }
        };
```

And when you want to exit from this process call:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

It will remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @mudit..thank you for reply..can you update the whole code? I am new to android.

Comment: Also if you think it is the correct solution then accept the answer and also do an upvote for it.